# Flutter - change enableDrag and isDismissible on a showModalBottomSheet after the modal has been rendered

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I would like to change the state my showModalBottomSheet is in. Specifically change enableDrag and isDismissible between true/false without showing a new modal or replacing the one that is already rendered. Is this currently possible at all?

```
bool allowDismiss = false; // change this variable after render

showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          isScrollControlled: true,
          isDismissible: allowDismiss, 
          enableDrag: allowDismiss,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius:
                BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30), topRight: Radius.circular(30)),
          ),
          builder: (context) => Container(height: 400),
        )
```

Comment: you want to change the behaviour based on what condition?

Comment: Some state of the child view, ie I want to disable the dismiss behavior while I'm displaying a loading state, but allow it while in any other state.

Comment: check this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/46685#issuecomment-598236647

Comment: Isn't that just the enableDrag property got implemented for showModalBottomSheet? What I want to do is change that variable AFTER the modal has been rendered.

Comment: You can set that property to follow a boolean that you save as a field in your class, and change it on some condition using `setState`

Comment: But that will that not just push a new modal to the navigation stack? Rather than rerender the modal.